# Apk won't appear at google play for certain devices

Tags: android

I uploaded my android app in google play in manifest I have these permissions:

```
    <compatible-screens>
     <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />


</compatible-screens>
```

but it won't appear when trying to download it from my tablet what could be wrong?

Comment: add the xlarge screensizes and the xxhdpi screenDensities

Comment: To declare the screen sizes your application supports, you should include the `<supports-screens>` element in your manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this in AndoridManifiest.xml file

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: ok but i don't won't 10'' tablets to be able to download it, not yet at least

Comment: set android:xlargeScreens="false"

Please refer       http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#support-screens

AND

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: should i let the compatible screens as is?

Comment: supports-screens tag is enough. Remove compatible-screens tag and test it. If it solves the problem then no need of compatible-screens tag. Hope your problem solved.

Comment: it didn't work...should I set xlargeScreens also true?

Comment: generally xlargeScreens is used for Tablets. If your application is supporting tablets then make it true.

Comment: as I said before i want to exclude 10'' tablets

Comment: Use android:requiresSmallestWidthDp tag. it will restrict to install in 10" tablet.

Comment: oh, what's the value i should set that tag?

Comment: set 600dp if you want to support max  7" tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Tablets are considered xlarge. Here is the reff document: [have a look at the "Range of screens supported section"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: in my project I've written layout files only for normal and large screens. If 7'' tablets were considered xlarge screens I wouldn't be able to see my app in my tablet